# Convertir web.config a .htaccess

Tags: apache

Me gustaría convertir este web.config

```
<rule name="cambiarPass" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^cambiarPass/" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="modulos/cambiarPass/controller.php" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

a un .htaccess
Por favor su ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: ya he retirado mi voto de cierre.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás buscando sería algo como esto:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^cambiarPass/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ modulos/cambiarPass/controller.php [L]
```

---

Lo que significa:

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^cambiarPass/`:

  Esta es la misma condición que tienes: si la URL comienza con "cambiarPass/"
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ modulos/cambiarPass/controller.php [L]`

  Entonces cambia la petición completamente (`^(.*)$` sería todo) por la URL a la que quieres ir (la de controller.php).

  Además, con la bandera `[L]` estás indicando que si se cumple esta regla debería ser la última (**L**ast) y ya no debería seguir procesando más reglas (equivalente al `stopProcessing="true"`)